# How can I get all the branches of a project using Gitlab API?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

Trying to get all the branches under a project using GitLab API, but I can see only 20 branches are returned. How can I get the complete list of all the branches? I am using the following API.

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <token>" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/1521/repository/branches"
```

Comment: If does not send you back all, maybe try with `?search=*` at the end. Should force to match all

Comment: As mentioned in the answers below, results are returned on a per-page basis.  You can extend the page length, but that option may break in the future as the results list grows.  A more extensible option is to iterate through the pages until an empty set is returned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the solution under pagination in the official [Gitlab API documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/rest/index.html#pagination), by default we get 20 results, we can increase the number of results by using `per_page` in our API link as follows.

```
https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<Project_id>/repository/branches?per_page=50
```

Comment: Ah, you found the answer, while I was still struggling to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Getting branches is limited to 20 branches. In order to get all branches use query parameters like below:

```
https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/2009901/repository/branches/?page=2

https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/2009901/repository/branches/?per_page=100
```

Documentation can be found here:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/#pagination

This is missing in the Branches API documentation unfortunately:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/branches.html

Comment: Apparently page size has a max limit of 100. I tried to put 500 and it still only pulled back 100 branches. Our repo has 161 branches and I had to get the rest of the branches by going to the 2nd page: ?per_page=100&page=2